# Using MOD and nesting

Tags: vb6, division, nested

I'm quite new to using VB, and I'm a beginner at programming, so I apologise for the poor/untidy code :P

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. The program should get 3 numbers from the user, and those 3 numbers have to add up, then be divisible by 3 to be valid. Also, the number cannot be 1 less than the previous number. Failure to follow these 'rules' should result in a message box saying "INVALID SIDESWAP". I believe it is a problem with the MOD section, as no matter what I input, it always returns "VALID SIDESWAP". Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
Dim FirstNumber, SecondNumber, ThirdNumber As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = FirstNumber
    TextBox2.Text = SecondNumber
    TextBox3.Text = ThirdNumber

    If (FirstNumber + SecondNumber + ThirdNumber) Mod 3 = 0 Then
        If (FirstNumber - SecondNumber) <> 1 And (SecondNumber - ThirdNumber) <> 1 And (ThirdNumber - FirstNumber) <> 1 Then
            MsgBox("VALID SIDESWAP")
        Else
            MsgBox("INVALID SIDESWAP 1")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("INVALID SIDESWAP 2")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming this is all the code, your `FirstNumber`, `SecondNumber`, `ThirdNumber` aren't ever getting set. They default to a value of 0, which means that you'll always get "VALID". I think you have the first 3 lines in your Click method backwards. If you want to set `FirstNumber` to whatever's in `TextBox1`, then you need to use `FirstNumber = TextBox1.Text`. Of course then you also need to verify that `TextBox1.Text` is a valid number.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it. Seems like a stupid error to make :P

Comment: Be aware that your code, as it stands, declares `FirstNumber` and `SecondNumber` as implicit Variants rather than Integers.  I assume you wanted to write `Dim FirstNumber As Integer, SecondNumber As Integer, ThirdNumber As Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

What heirich said is true, and will fix the problem, as long as you do enter Numbers in the textbox.
If you want to avoid any error the quick way is:

```
Firstnumber = val(Textbox1.text)
```

etc.
You are using Integers for firstnumber, val will also recognize Decimals, so you can use cdbl as well.

```
Firstnumber = cdbl(Textbox1.text)
```

But Empty Textboxes will generate an error, so use a combination

```
Firstnumber = cdbl(val(Textbox1.text))
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I will add that in aswell 
:)